# How do I express a time point which is a decade ago, counting from another time point mentioned in a passage?

Tags: time, past-vs-present

E.g., I would like to say

> X was almost impossible to be used in research until 2000s despite being invented a decade ago

In this sentence, I would like to express that X was invented in 1990s.

Would this sentence be understandable? Or do I have to say

> ...despite being invented in 1990s?

I would like to emphasize the temporal relationship if possible.

Comment: "Was almost impossible to be used" is clumsy and poor English. Most of the answers provide alternatives that would be used by educated English native speakers.

Comment: Also, "research" is a mass noun,  so is generally not pluralized.

Comment: I'd write “was invented in [year] but rarely used in research before [year]”.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using *ago* is ambiguous at best, and misleading at worst. (Because *ago* is naturally assumed to be relative to *now*, not the other date.)

You are free to give a specific date.

Or you can use some other words instead of *ago*:

> . . . was not used in research until 2000, despite being invented a decade *prior*.
>   . . . was not used in research until 2000, despite being invented a decade *before then*.
>   . . . was not used in research until 2000, despite being invented *in the previous decade*.

Comment: "...decade before" also works, if you wish to omit the "then".

Comment: I like _prior_; as this sounds like kind of a formal piece of writing:  "The Internet was almost impossible to use in research until the 2000s, despite being invented a decade prior."  Also, you might want to say, "...use _for_ research..."

Comment: @TomHundt — I hate "prior". Use "previously" as was done in the 20th century. That way you maintain the continuity of the English language rather than following the latest linguistic fad.

Comment: @David "Prior" was commonly used in this way in the 20th century — and the 19th. It's not any sort of fad. And it isn't so unwieldy as "previously".

Comment: @hobbs — When you are as old and pedantic as me, you will have no doubt about linguistic fashions. I'm away with only my phone at the moment, but I'll provide evidence when I return.

Comment: I also feel "previously" is more natural usage, but don't have citations handy to back myself up.

Comment: I don't like the use of "being" in these examples. Ought it not to be the present perfect continuous, "having been"? I.e. "...despite having been invented a decade earlier".

Comment: Prior is exactly the right word here. +1

Comment: See this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+year+prior%2C+a+year+previously&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20year%20prior%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20year%20previously%3B%2Cc0) for relative uses of "a year prior" and "a year previously".

Answer (score 34):

"xxx was almost impossible to use in researches until 2000s despite being invented a decade ***earlier***."

Collins:

> **[earlier](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/earlier)**
>
> 2. *adverb* [ADVERB with verb]
>      Earlier is **used to refer to a point or period in time** before the present or **before the one you
>      are talking about**.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Usage Example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Columbia):

> Columbia was destroyed at about 09:00 EST on February 1, 2003 while
>   re-entering the atmosphere after a 16-day scientific mission. The
>   Columbia Accident Investigation Board determined that a hole was
>   punctured in the leading edge on one of Columbia's wings, which was
>   made of a carbon composite. The hole had formed when a piece of
>   insulating foam from the external fuel tank peeled off during the
>   launch 16 days **earlier** and struck the shuttle's left wing.

Here it is clear that 16 days is with respect to Feb 1, 2003 and not *now*.

Comment: Or 'a decade before'.

Comment: Yes, *earlier* and *before* are clearly the best adverbs to use here.

Comment: "Was almost impossible to be used" is poor English and although used by the poster should not be repeated.

Answer (score 6):

The correct adverb would be either **beforehand** or [@alwayslearning's suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471211/how-to-express-a-time-point-which-is-a-decade-ago-counting-from-another-time-po/471221#471221) of **earlier**, but the verb tense is also affected.

> *xxx remained unused in research until the 2000s despite **having been invented** a decade **beforehand***

The verb form here reinforces that the invention is already in the past, at the point being discussed.

But it's probably clearer if you stick to chronological order:

> Despite being invented in the 1990s, *xxx* remained unused in research for another decade.

Answer (score 0):

What about rephrasing this to something like:

> It took almost a decade for X to be used in research following its invention in 199x.

This way you can stress that it was hard to apply X (probably because it required cheaper Y, or faster Z), not just stating the facts.

(I assume here) Since you talk about science, you probably can use this opportunity to cite some papers:

> Invented in 1990s [ref 1], it took almost a decade to see the first application of X in research [ref 2]

Answer (score 0):

Despite being invented in the early 1990s, it was almost impossible to use X in research until nearly a decade later

Answer (score 0):

I'd change **ago** for **before**,  i.e.:

> X was almost impossible to be used in research until 2000s, despite
>   being invented a decade **before**